# folder and files permission for magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I am download magento 2.0. Please tell me the folder and files permission for magento 2.0.

I give the 777 permission to all folders and files, setup wizard not working.

Thank you.

Comment: read Magento doc,here is well defined  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set the correct folder permissions like so:

```
find app/code pub/static app/etc var/generation var/di var/view_preprocessed vendor \( -type f -or -type d \) -exec chmod u-w {} \; && chmod o-rwx app/etc/env.php && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

**You should never give a file the 777 permissions.**

Comment: is there any way to install the magento 2.0 without composer? @david

Comment: Yes, sure but not recommended. You can download it here https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset all permission using following ssh command.

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755 && find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644
```